# "/.:/" in Exploiting VulnServer TRUN command

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit

I am currently studying about exploitation basics on buffer overflow, and I had the following problem.

When flooding buffers to the vulnserver, the syntax is like [The following is when EID is found after 2003 bytes, but doesnt really matter]

```
shellcode = "TRUN /.:/" + "A"*2003 + "B"*4
    
    s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('10.0.2.15', 9999))
    s.send(shellcode.encode())
    s.close()
```

I was wondering about why the syntax is **"TRUN /.:/"** not simply **"TRUN "**

I tried to google but still cannot find what is the meaning of **"/.:/"**

Answer (score 0):

TRUN will not crash without the "." because of the [if condition](https://github.com/stephenbradshaw/vulnserver/blob/master/vulnserver.c#L208).

The vulnerable function is called only when there is a '.' in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You are likely to see the `TRUN /.:/` command in most syntaxes used because most people follow the same process to perform Spiking -- a process for finding out what sequence of characters if sent to a program will cause the program to crash.

---

To add to the above answer. Yes, the syntax does not necessarily need to be `TRUN /.:/` , it can also be `TRUN .` .

Let me give a quick context. When running a buffer overflow attack, your starting point will likely be to throw a bunch of characters at the program to find out what sequence of characters cause the program to crash. Depending on how the program is written, this can be an `if` condition (like in the case of the TRUN command), or it can be the null character ('\0') vulnerability in the `strlen()` function in C. The point is, manually going through the code to figure out what vulnerability exists isn't the smartest way to go. And so, the usual starting point is to throw a bunch of random characters on the program to see what 'sticks' (that is, what causes the program to crash) - a process known as Spiking.

Most articles you see using the `TRUN /.:/` syntax likely followed the same Spiking process (maybe using the `generic_send_tcp` command) and once they find a crash using `TRUN /.:/`, they did not bother finding out what exact character(s) caused the crash, they just continue with the rest of the buffer overflow attack.